# Plotting quantity of teachers per county on a map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I have two data sets MASS and MASS2 to create a map in R. I got the first one with the help of library(ggmap).

```
counties<-map_data('county')
MASS<-map_data('county', 'massachusetts')

 str(MASS)
 data.frame':   744 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ long       : num  -70.7 -70.5 -70.5 -70.5 -70.5 ...
 $ lat        : num  41.7 41.8 41.8 41.8 41.8 ...
 $ group      : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ state      : chr  "massachusetts" "massachusetts" "massachusetts"  ...
 $ county_name: chr  "barnstable" "barnstable" "barnstable" "barnstable" ...
```

The second consists of 14 points one per each county and has a teacher's quantity data per that county.

```
 str(MASS2)
'data.frame':   14 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ state        : chr  "massachusetts" "massachusetts" "massachusetts" ...
 $ county_name  : chr  "barnstable" "berkshire" "bristol" "dukes" ...
 $ long         : num  -70.7 -73.5 -71.2 -70.5 -71 ...
 $ lat          : num  41.7 42 41.7 41.4 42.4 ...
 $ group        : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ teacher_count: int  62 40 47  ...
```

I need to create a map where each teacher_count point will be represented by a circle in accordance with teacher's amount. So far I'm getting just one size circles.

My code is next:

```
 ggplot(MASS, aes(long,lat, group = group)) +
 geom_polygon(aes(fill = county_name),colour = "black") +
 geom_point(data = MASS2, aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "red", size = 5)+
 theme(legend.position="none") +
 coord_quickmap()
```

[This is the map I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozHpv.jpg)

I found one solution online which offers to represent the size in geom_point as

```
 +geom_point(......, size = MASS2$teacher_count*circle_scale_amt)+
  scale_size_continuous(range=range(MA$teacher_count))
```

but R can't find circle_scale_amt.

I am a new to R and trying to learn. Will appreciate ideas for any other ways to represent the teachers by their quantity! Thank you!

Comment: Can you run `dput(MASS2)` then add the output to your question?

Comment: @Tung please see the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me after setting a value for `circle_scale_amt` to rescale the size of the points otherwise they would be too big.

```r
library(ggmap)

counties <- map_data('county')
MASS <- map_data('county', 'massachusetts')

circle_scale_amt <- 0.05

ggplot(MASS, aes(long,lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = subregion),colour = "black") +
  geom_point(data = MASS2, aes(x = long, y = lat), 
             size = MASS2$teacher_count * circle_scale_amt,
             color = "red", alpha = 0.6)+
  scale_size_continuous(range = range(MASS2$teacher_count)) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  coord_quickmap()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked!
I though circle_scale_amt is a build in function. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow. Needed a moment to figure out how to accept :) Thank you! @Tung